# Что нужно знать Junior PHP developer?

Tags: php

Что нужно знать чтобы стать Junior PHP developer?

Comment: Основы программирования, минимальные приемы (паттерны), конструкцию языка, PSR

Comment: @ilyaplot это то, что нужно знать в начале обучения, а реально для работы - действительно SQL, HTML и около того.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как раз ссыль увидел недавно, более подробно тут => http://anton.shevchuk.name/php/required-skills-for-junior-php-developer/

**SQL/MySQL**

Основы синтаксиса SQL требуются практически от всех программистов, будь то веб-разработка, или мобильная, вам же надо немного вникнуть в MySQL и понимать различия между MyISAM и InnoDB. Знать как работают LEFT/RIGHT/INNER JOIN’ы.

**HTML и CSS**

Сверстайте пару страниц, от и до. Не слушайте, что это работа дизайнера/верстальщика/кого-то еще. Поверьте моему опыту — вам отдадут свёрстанную страницу, никто за вас не будет интегрировать HTML шаблон в вашу систему, так что знание HTML и CSS в обязательном порядке. И забудьте о том, что верстальщики будут готовые шаблоны вам отдавать — это сказки.

Разберитесь с селекторами в CSS, следующий код не должен вызывать у вас ужаса:

```
#my p.sel:first-line, .main li li a:hover + span {
    color:#f00; /* Что это за цвет? Включи логику! */
}
```

**JavaScript**

Несмотря на то, что PHP это бэкенд разработка, знания JavaScript’а вам сильно пригодятся — особое внимание уделите изучению следующих моментов:

- синтаксис знать нужно в обязательном порядке
- понимать область видимости переменных
- познать замыкания
- изучить события, и разобраться со «всплытием»
- AJAX — что за зверь, как работает

**PHP**

Как вам списочек вышеописанных скилов? И это мы ещё не добрались к PHP ;)

PHP начинается с основ языка:

- нужно знать что такое переменные и константы
- типы данных, приведение типов и сравнение данных
- область видимости переменных
- приоритеты операторов
- побитовые операции
- управляющие конструкции
- пространства имён
- чуток затронуть строковые функции, такие как:
- explode()
- str_replace()
- strpos()
- substr()
- trim()
- но их куда больше…

работать с массивами нужно постоянно — функций много, я бы обратил внимание на следующие:

- array_push()
- array_pop()
- array_map()
- array_keys() и array_values()
- семейство array_diff и array_intersect
- различные сортировки
- поиск по массиву in_array() и array_key_exists()
- работа с файлами и файловой системой тоже вполне тривиальная задача
- порекомендую досконально изучить как работает подключение файлов
- и понять как происходит работа с сессиями
- узнать на практике как обрабатывать входные данные с форм
- поработать с базой данных с помощью PDO

А ещё нужно иметь представление об объектной модели в PHP:

- наследование
- область видимости свойств и методов
- магические методы
- обработка ошибок с помощью исключений

Дополнительно требуется:

- понимание паттерна MVC
- уметь работать в IDE отличной от текстового редактора
- знание английского на уровне понимания примеров на stackoverflow

Так что ещё забыл, ах да — система контроля версий:

- пройдите обучалку по Git на Code Academy либо GitHub
- почитайте Git Book
- заведите аккаунт на GitHub
- сохраните в закладки GitHub Guides

Comment: PHP программист не должен знать JS. И верстать не должен. Эти навыки нужны только _абстрактному веб-разработчику_. Ну и "веб-разработчик" != "PHP программист"

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нигде и не написано что должен, там написано пригодятся. Да и если проглядеть проекты на фрилансерах всяких, заказчики этого не понимают, предлагают работу html+css+js+php.